# How to get second value of second column in output

Tags: bash, awk

I have an output like this:

```
NAME              CLUSTER_IP     EXTERNAL_IP   PORT(S)    SELECTOR                  AGE
docker-registry   172.30.131.5   <none>        5000/TCP   docker-registry=default   33m
```

Now I want to get the IP. Nothing else.
I used `awk` but always got CLUSTER_IP with it too

```
result=$(oc get svc/docker-registry | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the 2nd line:

```
result=$(oc get svc/docker-registry | awk 'NR==2{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip the header line. Like this:

```
result=$(oc get svc/docker-registry | awk 'NR!=1{print $2}')
```